# Check if a financial firm/advisor is fraudulent/a scam in the UK (with an example)

Tags: united-kingdom, scams, fraud, legal, vanguard

I'm trying to understand the steps to follow to check if a financial firm/advisor is actually a scammer. For simplicity, lets stick to The UK.

I have found that there is something called [Financial Services Register](https://www.fca.org.uk/firms/financial-services-register) (FSR) which, apparently, can be used to check if a firm is authorized (by them), which in turn should mean that the firm in question is legal and not fraudulent. **Is this Financial Services Register trustworthy?**

To put a specific example, I try to verify that [Vanguard UK](https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/?cmpgn=PS0517UKBABRA0001&gclid=Cj0KCQiA_rfvBRCPARIsANlV66MwUBW9eerud6YCVWTX9FGfia8mQwAdKQUgonry0cpodhXV3par3xcaApIBEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) is actually verified. If I search for "Vanguard" in the FSR register, I find a list with several companies called "Vanguard" (see [FSR - Vanguard](https://register.fca.org.uk/shpo_searchresultspage?search=vanguard&TOKEN=3wq1nht7eg7tr)), so I'm not sure which one is the one I'm looking for.

Comment: Are there any other informations that is not provided by, either, PRA or FCA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regards to how trusty is the `FSR`, according to its web page:

> The Financial Services Register is a public record of firms, individuals and other bodies that are, or have been, regulated by the PRA and/or FCA.

The `PRA` is the [Prudential regulation](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/prudential-regulation), which belongs to The Bank Of England, which belongs to the UK goverment so I guess that it is trusty enough.

With regards to the [FCA (Financial Conduct Authority)](https://www.fca.org.uk/about), it seems to be a private institution, so not sure how trusty is this.

The above quote says **'and/or'**, so it might happen that an institution is granted by the `FCA` but not by the `PR`. A good question would be how to be sure if the `PR` has verified an institution.

For finding the right `Vanguard` entry in the list, in the `Vanguard` web page, go to the bottom and the following can be found:

```
©2019 Vanguard Asset Management, Limited. All rights reserved.
Issued by Vanguard Asset Management, Limited is authorised and regulated in the UK by the Financial Conduct Authority.
```

Going back to the FSR, there is one entry whose name is exactly `Vanguard Asset Management`. By clicking in that name, a report is shown with a link to the `Vanguard` web page. In addition, it shows the kind of protection that is supposed to be granted:
[FSR - Vanguard](https://register.fca.org.uk/ShPo_FirmDetailsPage?id=001b000000NMI0mAAH) (not sure until which point this is respected in case of fraud/scam)

Comment: The FCA is the UK's financial regulator so is as trustworthy as the laws in the UK